# Interface Builder warnings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit, interface-builder

I am getting an warning while building my source code as follows:

> /* com.apple.ibtool.document.warnings */
>   /Users/biranchi/Desktop/Hotlist v2.0/Classes/HLCheckinViewController.xib:6: warning: The separator style "Single Line Etched" is not supported on iPhone OS versions prior to 3.2.

What is this error due to ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you are using a grouped table with the separator style set to "Single line etched" and are compiling with SDK 3.1.3. In interface builder change the separator style to "Single line" and rebuild.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to setting the project's deployment target, XIB files have their own deployment version. Select the XIB file in Xcode, and go to the File Inspector (View -> Utilities -> File Inspector), under the "Interface Builder Document" section of the inspector, and set "Deployment" to at least iOS 3.2.

Comment: After spending much time with a cryptic message, I now see that the build version had nothing to do with the message, but rather the IB version. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Dont' play with tableview separator property in the interface builder..... I just keep separator as it is in the IB is "single lined" and in ViewWillappear or viewdidload add below line..

```
tableview.separatorStyle = tableview.UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLineEtched
```